# ¿Cómo hacer que deje de aparecer  cuando redimensiono un elemento?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo este código que me redimensiona el cuadrado celeste, pero a veces cuando pulso el mouse sobre lo azul oscuro para redimensinarlo y lo muevo rápidamente me aparece esto: (en negro) y no se porque ocurre.

```js
const elemento = document.querySelector(".elemento");
let mover = false;
let X;
let Y;

document.querySelector(".f").addEventListener("mousedown", amover);
function comprobar(e){ 
  if(mover == true){
    X = derecha(e, X);
  }
  return;
};

window.addEventListener("mousemove", comprobar);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', eliminar);

function amover(e){
  X = e.clientX;
  Y = e.clientY;
  mover = true;
}

function eliminar(){
  mover = false;
};

document.ondragstart = function(){return;}

function derecha(e, X){
  const width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elemento).width) - (X - e.clientX);
  if(width < 1)return X;
  elemento.style.width = width + "px";
  document.querySelector(".f").style.left = elemento.getBoundingClientRect().right + "px";
  X = e.clientX;
  return X;
}
```

```css
.f {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:3;
  cursor: e-resize;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 50px;
}

.elemento {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<p class="f"></p>
<p class="elemento"></p>
```

He intentado resolverlo poniendo window a los dos controladores de eventos de mousemove y mouseup y document.ondragstart = function(){return;} (también intente poner window en vez de document y me daba lo mismo) para que no se genere un conflicto con la API de drag and drop, pero nose que falla.
¿Porqué me aparece el  y cómo lo soluciono? Muchisimas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu elemento, están ocurriendo dos eventos:

- Evento de arrastre.
- Evento de selección.

Y al querer arrastrar muy rápido, estás seleccionando el elemento antes de querer arrastrarlo, es decir, está ocurriendo primero el evento de selección antes que el de arrastre, y pienso que te sale el  porque no te permite seleccionar el elemento.

Entonces quitemos el evento de selección con la propiedad de CSS [**`user-select: none;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/user-select), así no seleccionas el elemento y solo ocurre el de arrastre, ejemplo:

```js
const elemento = document.querySelector(".elemento");
let mover = false;
let X;
let Y;

document.querySelector(".f").addEventListener("mousedown", amover);
function comprobar(e){ 
  if(mover == true){
    X = derecha(e, X);
  }
  return;
};

window.addEventListener("mousemove", comprobar);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', eliminar);

function amover(e){
  X = e.clientX;
  Y = e.clientY;
  mover = true;
}

function eliminar(){
  mover = false;
};

document.ondragstart = function(){return;}

function derecha(e, X){
  const width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(elemento).width) - (X - e.clientX);
  if(width < 1)return X;
  elemento.style.width = width + "px";
  document.querySelector(".f").style.left = elemento.getBoundingClientRect().right + "px";
  X = e.clientX;
  return X;
}
```

```css
.f {
  width: 20px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:3;
  cursor: e-resize;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 50px;
  user-select: none; /* indico que no se pueda seleccionar */
}

.elemento {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<p class="f"></p>
<p class="elemento"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas javascript para cambiar el tamaño, solo con CSS puedes lograrlo mediante la regla [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/resize) e incluso con algo más de estilo puedes llegar a tener lo mismo que tu ejemplo

```css
.elemento {
  height: 50px;
  width: 70px;
  background-color: aqua;
  resize:horizontal;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.elemento::-webkit-resizer {
    background-color: blue;
}
.elemento::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 20px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p class="elemento"></p>
```